# Outputting Folder Column Defaults in a List

Tags: powershell, metadata

I have   folders in a library which have default values set for certain folders through the library settings
I know the values are their because I can see them and they get applied to documents. I was trying to find a way to output those default values using power shell. The script below

http://blogs.technet.com/b/okoestner/archive/2011/12/01/fetch-default-values-of-folders-with-powershell.aspx
Looked promising but when I run it it reports the values as blank even though they definately there. It does read the library I specify and all folders but the value is always reported as blank. Just wondering if anyone can spot anything in the script itself that isn't quite kosher.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I needed to put in the internal column name. Works like a dream now.